# How to map and filter JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I would like to filter following JSON.

```
   members = {members:[{id: 1, name: "aaa"},{id: 2, name: "bbb"},{id: 3, name: "ccc"}]}
```

How can I use map function with filter more than `id: 2`.
My idea is following. But it does not work.

```
    {this.props.members.map((member) => (
        if((member.id > 10) && (member.id < 20) ){
          <a key={member.id} href="#">
            {member.name}
          </a>
       }
    ))}
```

How can I do for it?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: So, use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before `map`? Like this: `this.props.members.filter(m => m.id > 10 && m.id < 20).map(m => <a key={} href=...)`

Comment: i dont think `members = {members:[{id: 1, name: "aaa"},{id: 2, name: "bbb"},{id: 3, name: "ccc"}]}` is  the valid json

Comment: You might need to use `members.members`

Comment: @techguru it’s not JSON, but a standard JS object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox than in that case , the question may be misguiding

Comment: @techguru I guess it is.

Comment: @adiga .  no need a filter loop .you could validate the condition with inline of map function `Array.map(m => m.id > 10 && <a key={} href=...)` .inline && operator

Comment: @prasanth ah, updated with a react duplicate. Does react ignore all [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values or just `false`?

Comment: @prasanth `undefined` also doesn't get displayed. So, all OP has to do is add a return before their JSX. `if(member.id > 10 && member.id < 20) return ( <a href .... />)`

Comment: @adiga yes. but this above case not possible  `id:undefined` of any other `falsy` case.And  `&&` also same as [`filter` working](https://jsfiddle.net/prasanth1036/5rjmvy2o/1/).when `id:undefined`   filter also ignore the value .i just said no need a filter loop before .  `&&` is not react specific its a default js condition.you can use `||` also inside map same as your `filter`

Comment: @prasanth I meant if `map` returns undefined, it will not be displayed. So, OP just needs to add return around their JSX: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-blackwell-2qf5t

Comment: @adiga. On your first comment you are directly return the JSX. without return string.That why i suggest like this https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-night-ij5ng .you could use like this there is no undefined return without filter loop.you can add your filter condition with inline map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-night-ij5ng)**

You are loop the object not a array . And display only above `id:2` use with `&&` operator . `condition && object.key`

```
{this.props.members.members.map(
        member =>
          member.id > 2 && (
            <p key={member.id} href="#">
              {member.name}
            </p>
          )
      )}
```

Answer (score 2):

First convert your JSON to regular js, filter through the response for your desired content and then map through them

```
(JSON.parse(this.props.members).members.filter(member => member.id >2)).map(content => (<a key={content.id} href="#">{content.name} </a>)
```